# Likelihood and Probability

Tags: bayesian, maximum-likelihood, likelihood

So to my understanding, Probabilities are areas under fixed distribution, which can be expressed mathematically probability of data given distribution:  $$P(Data|Distribution)$$
Whereas likelihoods are the y axis values for fixed data points with distributions that can be moved. So, mathematically
$$L(Distribution|data)$$
If the above is true, then why is it when I am trying to find Likelihood of exponential distribution is: $$P(X_{1},X_{2},\cdots X_{n}|\lambda)=P(X_{1}|\lambda)\cdot P(X_{2}|\lambda)\cdots P(X_{n}|\lambda)$$
So that means it is distribution is given not the data as I defined earlier for likelihood. I feel like I have a dumb misunderstanding when it comes to likelihood.

Comment: The functional form is the same when written out, but in the first case (probabilities) what varies are the data, whereas in the second case (likelihoods,) what varies are the parameters.  So... the probability distribution and the likelihood are actually two different functions, although to the unwary viewer they appear the same.

Comment: I know that we are varying parameters in likelihood, then shouldnt it be L(data | parameters)?